# Swift - 'NSArray' is not of type 'inout C'

Tags: ios, nsarray, swift

I'm getting this error in XCode beta 3. Don't know whether this is a bug or if I'm doing something I shouldn't. Anyway, this is an example that I read on Apple's official documentation.
Here's the code:

```
var names = ["Mark" , "Bob" , "Tracy" , "John"]

var reversed = sort(names , { (s1: String , s2: String) -> Bool in return s1 > s2
})
```

It is a simple sort using a closure.

Comment: `let` defines a constant and you're tyring to change the order of elements inside the constant array. Try using `var` instead.

Comment: @Eimantas `names` is not being changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several problems here:

Never declare a generic without specifying its type. Don't use `Array`, use `Array<String>`. However, in this case, you don't need the `: Array<String` part, you don't need the typing `as Array<String>`. Just let the type be inferred.

```
let names = ["Mark", "Bob", "Tracy", "John"]
```

Now, this is a constant array. Array is a value type. Constant value types cannot be modified.

The `sort` function is trying to sort the array. It doesn't create a new array, it sorts the one you pass as a parameter. However, since it is a value type, it cannot be a constant and you have to pass it by reference:

```
var names = ["Mark", "Bob", "Tracy", "John"]
sort(&names, >)
```

If you don't want to sort the original array and you want to create a new array instead, use `sorted` function.

```
let names = ["Mark", "Bob", "Tracy", "John"]
let sortedNames = sorted(names, >)
```

Note this has changed substantially between Beta 2 and Beta 3.

Comment: Thanks sulthan. using sorted solved my problem. However, even if I change the declared array type to var I'm not able to use the sort method.

Comment: @vyudi Did you add the `&`?

Comment: @Sulthan Since Arrays are immutable (structs) how does just making it a var solve the problem, what is going on behind the scenes?

Comment: But the Array is a struct and structs are not modifiable.

Comment: @Zaph If you make it `var`, then it's mutable.

Comment: OK I understand that works. From the docs I got that one main difference between structs and classes was that structs were immutable and classes were mutable, I will re-read.

Comment: @Zaph The difference is more about being passed by reference and being passed by value (that's why we call them object types and value types).

Comment: @Zaph Structs are mutable if you declare them as `var`. Declaring them as `let` makes them immutable.